# How can I find each table cell's "visual location" using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, algorithm, html-table

I have a HTML table that contains both ROWSPANs and COLSPANs.

How can I find each cell's "visual location" using jQuery?

For example, here's a visual representation of my table with each cell populated with what the "visual location" algorithm should return:
*(Note: I only really care about cells within the `<tbody>` and the column reference can be an integer, not an alphabetic character, I've only done this to easily highlight the problem)*

```
+--+--+--+--+--+
|  |A |B |C |D |
+--+--+--+--+--+
|1 |A1|B1   |D1|
+--+--+--+--+  +
|2 |A2   |C2|  |
+--+     +--+  +
|3 |     |C3|  |
+--+--+--+--+--+
|4 |A4|B4|C4|D4|
+--+--+--+--+--+
|XYZ           |
+--+--+--+--+--+
```

I've tried implementing the first, however the reference for cell C3 is inaccurate as it doesn't take into account ROWSPANS. The second link may be able to be merged into the solution of the first, but I can't figure out how.

- [Working with tables in jQuery | My Tech World](http://mytechworld.officeacuity.com/index.php/2009/09/working-with-tables-in-jquery/)
- [What's the most efficient way to retrieve the column of rows affected by a "rowspan"? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1452582)

I'm hoping to use this as a function called `getCellLocation(cell)` that will return an associative array that returns the location something like this:

```
function getCellLocation(cell)
{
  var row_number = parseInt($(cell).parent().prevAll().length) + 1;
  var col_number = 1;
  $(cell).prevAll('td').each(function() {
      col_number += $(this).attr('colspan') ? parseInt($(this).attr('colspan')) : 1;
  });

  var location = new Array();
  location['row'] = row_number;
  location['col'] = col_number;
  location['index'] = $('td').index(cell) + 1;
  return location;
}

$('table td').each(function(i){
  var cell = getCellLocation($(this));
  $(this).prepend('<span class="ref">R' + cell['row'] + ':C' + cell['col'] + ':D' + cell['index'] + '</span>');
});
```

Here's the HTML of the example table:

```
<table border="1" cellspacing="0">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>A</th>
      <th>B</th>
      <th>C</th>
      <th>D</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>1</th>
      <td>A1</td>
      <td colspan="2">B1</td>
      <td rowspan="3">D1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>2</th>
      <td rowspan="2" colspan="2">A2</td>
      <td>C2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>3</th>
      <td>C3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>4</th>
      <td>A4</td>
      <td>B4</td>
      <td>C4</td>
      <td>D4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="5">XYZ</td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
<style> span { background-color: #ffc; margin-right: .5em;} </style>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's my solution:

```
function getCellLocation(cell) {

    var cols = cell.closest("tr").children("td").index(cell);
    var rows = cell.closest("tbody").children("tr").index(cell.closest("tr"));
    var coltemp = cols;
    var rowtemp = rows;

    cell.prevAll("td").each(function() {
        cols += ($(this).attr("colspan")) ? parseInt($(this).attr("colspan")) - 1 : 0;
    });

    cell.parent("tr").prevAll("tr").each(function() {
        //get row index for search cells
        var rowindex = cell.closest("tbody").children("tr").index($(this));
        // assign the row to a variable for later use
        var row = $(this);
        row.children("td").each(function() {
            // fetch all cells of this row
            var colindex = row.children("td").index($(this));
            //check if this cell comes before our cell
            if (cell.offset().left > $(this).offset().left) {
                // check if it has both rowspan and colspan, because the single ones are handled before
                var colspn = parseInt($(this).attr("colspan"));
                var rowspn = parseInt($(this).attr("rowspan"));
                if (colspn && rowspn) {
                    if(rowindex + rowspn > rows)
                    cols += colspn;                    
                }
                if(rowspn && rowindex + rowspn > rows) cols +=1;
            }

        });
    });
```

I'm checking for cells which have both colspan and rowspan, because the rest are handled by the first five lines of this code. If the cells have both rowspan and colspan, they should be effecting other cells that are not below OR aside this cell, so I need to search for every cell's previous cells for interaction.

Comment: There seems to be a slight issue or double counting in some scenarios. Consider the result when it's applied to this table (see cell Col3 Row2): [http://jsfiddle.net/tUn54/](http://jsfiddle.net/tUn54/)

Comment: If the table is expected wider, there is still something funky. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/tUn54/2/ (Row2Col9, Row2Col12, Row5Col9, Row5Col12)

Comment: Ok, I've tried another method. This is more reliable because it uses the offset position of the cell to calculate the previous interaction. Here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/TRr6C/3/. And I'll update the code.

Comment: @tpaksu have you got an update script as it doesn't work in this case http://jsfiddle.net/TRr6C/8/

Comment: I updated my code. Added one line: `if(rowspn && rowindex + rowspn > rows) cols +=1;`. and you can test it here : http://jsfiddle.net/TRr6C/16/

Comment: I wasn't checking for only row spanned cells, just the ones with both rowspans and colspans if I may explain why this update was necessary.

Comment: These are not used `var coltemp = cols; var rowtemp = rows;`. Thanks for the code!

Comment: @JānisElmeris yea, that time I wasn't using VSCode, but they were used at some point of the algorithm :)

Answer (score 1):

```
your solution        my proposed table design
+--+--+--+--+--+     +--+--+--+--+--+
|  |A |B |C |D |     |  |A |B |C |D |     length 5 vs 5
+--+--+--+--+--+     +--+--+--+--+--+
|1 |A1|B1   |D1|     |1 |A1|B1|//|D1|
+--+--+--+--+  +     +--+--+--+--+--+
|2 |A2   |C2|  |     |2 |A2|//|C2|//|     length 3 vs 5
+--+     +--+  +     +--+--+--+--+--+
|3 |     |C3|  |     |3 |//|//|C3|//|
+--+--+--+--+--+     +--+--+--+--+--+
|4 |A4|B4|C4|D4|     |4 |A4|B4|C4|D4|
+--+--+--+--+--+     +--+--+--+--+--+
|XYZ           |     |XY|//|//|//|//|     length 1 vs 5
+--+--+--+--+--+     +--+--+--+--+--+
```

```
// cells labeled '//' above have this class

td.stuffing { display: none; }
```

Do you see what I did there?

This is the third row, for example:

```
<tr>
  <th>2</th>
  <td rowspan="2" colspan="2">A2</td>
  <td class="stuffing"></td>
  <td>C2</td>
  <td class="stuffing"></td>
</tr>
```

Now the function to retrieve correct index is very simple.

```
function getCellLocation(cell) {
    return {row:cell.parentNode.rowIndex, cell:cell.cellIndex}
}
```

---

And here is a bonus. If you were to access a hidden cell, this will automatically traverse to the correct one, which spans over those hidden.

```
function getSmartCell(table, row, col) {
    var cell = table.rows[row].cells[col];
    if (cell.className.indexOf("stuffing") == -1) return cell;

    // traverse Left
    while ((row>0) && (col>0) && (cell.className.indexOf("stuffing") >= 0)) {
        cell = table.rows[row].cells[--col];
    }

    // roll back one cell if no colSpan is found
    if (cell.colSpan == 1) cell = table.rows[row].cells[++col];

    // traverse Up
    while ((row>0) && (col>0) && (cell.className.indexOf("stuffing") >= 0)) {
        cell = table.rows[--row].cells[col];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Usage:

```
var tb = document.querySelector("table");
getCellLocation(getSmartCell(tb,3,2)); // {row: 2, cell: 1}
```

**ATTENTION**
I have just checked the code of `getSmartCell` and it returns wrong result if there are two neighbouring rowspans. I need to fix this.

Here is an example https://jsfiddle.net/goua3m13/

Comment: there was a deliberate reason why cells where "merged" to span columns and rows in my question. For the use-case, it needed to be that way and couldn't use blank cells and hide them

Comment: @Turgs You can still use colspans and rowspans while also using hidden cells.

Answer (score 0):

for this specific layout (i.e. if your first row doesn't have colspan and more or less uniform cell borders) you may do it this way:

```
function getCellLocation(cell)
{
    var row_number = cell.parentNode.rowIndex;
    var col_number = "";
    $(cell).parents('table').find('tr:first th').each( function()
    {
        if (cell.offsetLeft >= this.offsetLeft)
        {
            col_number = $(this).text();
        }
        else return false;
    });
    return col_number + row_number;
}
```

if you want numeric column change it to

```
var col_number = 0;
    ...
if (cell.offsetLeft >= this.offsetLeft)
{
    col_number++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here a jQuery solution that is able to handle complex table structure. This solution use the [Open Source WxT Table Parser](https://github.com/wet-boew/wet-boew/blob/master/src/js/dependencies/parserTable.js) available here: https://raw.github.com/wet-boew/wet-boew/master/src/js/dependencies/parserTable.js

You will find the documentation in the [Table Usability Concept Github Repository](https://github.com/duboisp/Table-Usability-Concept). Use the API documentation that is under "Table Parser - WET 3.0 release".

The table parsing is done by using the HTML tabular markup and the visual relationships between the data cell (td) and the header cell (th)

```
// Used to get the reference to the WxT table parser
var _pe = window.pe || {
    fn : {}
};

// For each table elements
$('table').each(function () {

    var $tbl = $(this);

    // Parse the table
    _pe.fn.parsertable.parse($tbl);

    // For each data cell
    $('td', $tbl).each(function () {

        var $td = $(this),
            tblparser;

        // Get the API structure as defined under "Table Parser - WET 3.0 release" (https://github.com/duboisp/Table-Usability-Concept/blob/master/API/td.md#table-parser---wet-30-release)
        tblparser = $td.data().tblparser;

        // Set the cell location (x, y)
        $td.html(tblparser.row.rowpos + ', ' + tblparser.col.start);


    });
});
```

You will find a working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/TVttA/

Cheers

:-)

Answer (score 0):

Since the accepted answer is missing a `return` statement and only works with tbody and td (and not with thead and th) I did some slight adjustments to make it work:

```
function getCellLocation(cell) {

    var cols = cell.closest("tr").children("th, td").index(cell);
    var rows = cell.closest("thead, tbody").children("tr").index(cell.closest("tr"));

    cell.prevAll("th, td").each(function() {
        cols += ($(this).attr("colspan")) ? parseInt($(this).attr("colspan")) - 1 : 0;
    });

    cell.parent("tr").prevAll("tr").each(function() {
        //get row index for search cells
        var rowindex = cell.closest("thead, tbody").children("tr").index($(this));
        // assign the row to a variable for later use
        var row = $(this);
        row.children("th, td").each(function() {
            //check if this cell comes before our cell
            if (cell.offset().left > $(this).offset().left) {
                // check if it has both rowspan and colspan, because the single ones are handled before
                var colspn = parseInt($(this).attr("colspan"));
                var rowspn = parseInt($(this).attr("rowspan"));
                if (rowspn && rowindex + rowspn > rows) {
                    cols += colspn ? colspn : 1;
                }
            }

        });
    });
    return cols;
}
```