# Table cellIndex and rowIndex with colspan/rowspan

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I was using the answer provided in:

[How can I find each table cell's "visual location" using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10966687/how-can-i-find-each-table-cells-visual-location-using-jquery/10967488#10967488)

But it doesn't seem to work in this case: http://jsfiddle.net/TRr6C/9/

Notice the 1,3 1,4 and 2,4 should be 1,4 1,5 and 2,5

Anyone see whats wrong?

Or is there any better solution to get the cellIndex and rowIndex from a table cell taking into consideration colspan and rowspan?

Here is the code:

```
function getCellLocation(cell) {

    var cols = cell.closest("tr").children("td").index(cell);
    var rows = cell.closest("tbody").children("tr").index(cell.closest("tr"));
    var coltemp = cols;
    var rowtemp = rows;

    cell.prevAll("td").each(function() {
        cols += ($(this).attr("colspan")) ? parseInt($(this).attr("colspan")) - 1 : 0;
    });

    cell.parent("tr").prevAll("tr").each(function() {
        //get row index for search cells
        var rowindex = cell.closest("tbody").children("tr").index($(this));
        // assign the row to a variable for later use
        var row = $(this);
        row.children("td").each(function() {
            // fetch all cells of this row
            var colindex = row.children("td").index($(this));
            //check if this cell comes before our cell
            if (cell.offset().left > $(this).offset().left) {
                // check if it has both rowspan and colspan, because the single ones are handled before
                var colspn = parseInt($(this).attr("colspan"));
                var rowspn = parseInt($(this).attr("rowspan"));
                if (colspn && rowspn) {
                    if(rowindex + rowspn > rows)
                    cols += colspn;                    
                }
            }

        });
    });

    return {
        rows: rows,
        cols: cols
    };
}
```

Comment: By your logic 1,3 is wrong too, right? Should be 1,4.

Comment: @Hemlock yes, it should be 1,4

Comment: @Petah the issue is about the 'td' that have a colspan greater than 1 are not considerated when that cell is in a previous row. What you would like to do by getting the cellIndex and rowIndex? I may be able to provide a solution. Here a [jQuery complex table parser](https://github.com/wet-boew/wet-boew/blob/master/src/js/dependencies/parserTable.js) and your will find technical documentation [Table Usability Concept](https://github.com/duboisp/Table-Usability-Concept) and use example [HTML Tables and WET Table Parser](http://wet-boew.github.com/wet-boew/demos/tableparser/index-eng.html) :-)

Comment: It's not the colspan it's rowspan Sorry. So, the issue is about the 'td' that have a rowspan greater than 1 are not considerated when that cell is in a previous row. :-)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

My solution is in form of jQuery plugin since I can imagine more than one purpose of having this information. It can be used as in:

```
$("table tbody td").each(function(){ 
    $(this).text( $(this).cellPos().top +","+ $(this).cellPos().left );
});
```

The position is in form of `{ top: rows, left: cols }`.
On its first call, table is scanned and `TD` elements get `data` items with their cached position. (Cache can be rebuilt by calling with argument `true`). All further calls just return that cached value.

Hope this helps!

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TRr6C/17/)

Full source:

```
/*  cellPos jQuery plugin
    ---------------------
    Get visual position of cell in HTML table (or its block like thead).
    Return value is object with "top" and "left" properties set to row and column index of top-left cell corner.
    Example of use:
        $("#myTable tbody td").each(function(){ 
            $(this).text( $(this).cellPos().top +", "+ $(this).cellPos().left );
        });
*/
(function($){
    /* scan individual table and set "cellPos" data in the form { left: x-coord, top: y-coord } */
    function scanTable( $table ) {
        var m = [];
        $table.children( "tr" ).each( function( y, row ) {
            $( row ).children( "td, th" ).each( function( x, cell ) {
                var $cell = $( cell ),
                    cspan = $cell.attr( "colspan" ) | 0,
                    rspan = $cell.attr( "rowspan" ) | 0,
                    tx, ty;
                cspan = cspan ? cspan : 1;
                rspan = rspan ? rspan : 1;
                for( ; m[y] && m[y][x]; ++x );  //skip already occupied cells in current row
                for( tx = x; tx < x + cspan; ++tx ) {  //mark matrix elements occupied by current cell with true
                    for( ty = y; ty < y + rspan; ++ty ) {
                        if( !m[ty] ) {  //fill missing rows
                            m[ty] = [];
                        }
                        m[ty][tx] = true;
                    }
                }
                var pos = { top: y, left: x };
                $cell.data( "cellPos", pos );
            } );
        } );
    };

    /* plugin */
    $.fn.cellPos = function( rescan ) {
        var $cell = this.first(),
            pos = $cell.data( "cellPos" );
        if( !pos || rescan ) {
            var $table = $cell.closest( "table, thead, tbody, tfoot" );
            scanTable( $table );
        }
        pos = $cell.data( "cellPos" );
        return pos;
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Great work! This is the best implementation I've found so far.

Comment: Check out @Wesabi's answer below which is cleaner.

Answer (score 8):

vanilla js version of @nrodic 's scanTable()

```
function scanTable(table)
{
    var m = [];
    for(var y=0; y<table.rows.length; y++)
    {
        var row = table.rows[y];

        for(var x=0;x<row.cells.length;x++)
        {
            var cell = row.cells[x], xx = x, tx, ty;

            for(; m[y] && m[y][xx]; ++xx);                        // skip already occupied cells in current row

            for(tx = xx; tx < xx + cell.colSpan; ++tx)            // mark matrix elements occupied by current cell with true
            {
                for(ty = y; ty < y + cell.rowSpan; ++ty)
                {
                    if( !m[ty] ) m[ty] = [];                    // fill missing rows
                    m[ty][tx] = true;
                }
            }

            // do here whatever you want with
            // xx: the horizontal offset of the cell
            // y: the vertical offset of the cell

        }
    }
};
```

Comment: yes, since `table.rows` contains all rows of the table, including those that are in thead & tfoot - [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement.rows)

Comment: fixed a bug! x needed a copy (xx) for to function

Answer (score 6):

I have improved user652649's answer so that function returns cell according to given coordinates and does not miss cells with col/rowspan, [here is the gist](https://gist.github.com/ZitRos/a96c8e7f8c0fe4e16a31), or just a code:

```
/**
 * Returns the cell of the table by given (x;y) coordinates considering colSpan and rowSpan of the cells.
 * @param {HTMLElement} table - HTML table
 * @param {number} x - X position in table matrix
 * @param {number} y - Y position in table matrix
 * @returns {HTMLElement|null}
 */
var getTableCell = function (table, x, y) {
    var m = [], row, cell, xx, tx, ty, xxx, yyy;
    for(yyy = 0; yyy < table.rows.length; yyy++) {
        row = table.rows[yyy];
        for(xxx = 0; xxx < row.cells.length; xxx++) {
            cell = row.cells[xxx];
            xx = xxx;
            for(; m[yyy] && m[yyy][xx]; ++xx) {}
            for(tx = xx; tx < xx + cell.colSpan; ++tx) {
                for(ty = yyy; ty < yyy + cell.rowSpan; ++ty) {
                    if (!m[ty])
                        m[ty] = [];
                    m[ty][tx] = true;
                }
            }
            if (xx <= x && x < xx + cell.colSpan && yyy <= y && y < yyy + cell.rowSpan)
                return cell;
        }
    }
    return null;
};
```