# Iterate over table cells, re-using rowspan values

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I have a simple HTML table, which uses rowspans in some random columns.  An example might look like

```
 A | B |
---|---| C
 D |   |
---| E |---
 F |   | G
```

I'd like to iterate over the rows such that I see rows as `A,B,C`, `D,E,C`, then `F,E,G`.

I think I can probably cobble together something very convoluted using `cell.index()` to check for "missed" columns in later rows, but I'd like something a little more elegant...

Comment: What I've done so far is to save the left offset of each cell in the first row (since that's guaranteed to have as many `TD`s as columns in the table), then step through the row comparing offsets to see which column the cell "belongs" to.  Inspired by [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10966687/how-can-i-find-each-table-cells-visual-location-using-jquery/10967488#10967488) -- it works OK for now, but would break if I had any `colspans` and still feels clunky...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
    <table id="tbl">
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" rowspan="2">A</td>
        <td rowspan="2">C</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">E</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>F</td>
        <td>G</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

Script:

```
    var finalResult = '';
    var totalTds = $('#tbl TR')[0].length;
    var trArray = [];
    var trArrayValue = [];
    var trIndex = 1;
    $('#tbl TR').each(function(){
    var currentTr = $(this);
    var tdIndex = 1;
    trArray[trIndex] = [];
    trArrayValue[trIndex] = [];
    var tdActuallyTraversed = 0;
    var colspanCount = 1;
    $('#tbl TR').first().children().each(function(){
        if(trIndex > 1 && trArray[trIndex - 1][tdIndex] > 1)
        { 
            trArray[trIndex][tdIndex] = trArray[trIndex - 1][tdIndex] - 1;
            trArrayValue[trIndex][tdIndex] = trArrayValue[trIndex - 1][tdIndex];
            finalResult = finalResult + trArrayValue[trIndex][tdIndex];
        }
        else
        {                        
            if(colspanCount <= 1)
            {
                colspanCount = currentTr.children().eq(tdActuallyTraversed).attr('colspan') != undefined ? currentTr.children().eq(tdActuallyTraversed).attr('colspan') : 1;
            }
            if(colspanCount > 1 && tdIndex > 1)
            {
                trArray[trIndex][tdIndex] = currentTr.children().eq(tdActuallyTraversed + colspanCount).attr('rowspan') != undefined ?currentTr.children().eq(tdActuallyTraversed + colspanCount).attr('rowspan') : 1;
                trArrayValue[trIndex][tdIndex] = trArrayValue[trIndex][tdIndex - 1];
                colspanCount--;
            }
            else
            {
                trArray[trIndex][tdIndex] = currentTr.children().eq(tdActuallyTraversed).attr('rowspan') != undefined ?currentTr.children().eq(tdActuallyTraversed).attr('rowspan') : 1;
                trArrayValue[trIndex][tdIndex] = currentTr.children().eq(tdActuallyTraversed).html();
                tdActuallyTraversed++;
            }
            finalResult = finalResult + trArrayValue[trIndex][tdIndex];

        }

        tdIndex++;
    });
    trIndex++;
});

alert(finalResult);
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9yXPm/1/)

i am not sure about the performance, but it works well.

Comment: Update the Solution, now it covers colspan also

Answer (score 5):

without jquery:

```js
function tableToMatrix(table) {
  var M = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
    var tr = table.rows[i];
    M[i] = [];
    for (var j = 0, k = 0; j < M[0].length || k < tr.cells.length;) {
      var c = (M[i-1]||[])[j];
      // first check if there's a continuing cell above with rowSpan
      if (c && c.parentNode.rowIndex + c.rowSpan > i) {
        M[i].push(...Array.from({length: c.colSpan}, () => c))
        j += c.colSpan;
      } else if (tr.cells[k]) {
        var td = tr.cells[k++];
        M[i].push(...Array.from({length: td.colSpan}, () => td));
        j += td.colSpan;
      }
    }
  }
  return M;
}

var M = tableToMatrix(document.querySelector('table'));

console.table(M.map(r => r.map(c => c.innerText)));

var pre = document.createElement('pre');
pre.innerText = M.map(row => row.map(c => c.innerText).join('\t')).join('\n');
document.body.append(pre);
```

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.3);
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td colspan=2>A</td>

    <td rowspan=2>B</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>C</td>
    <td rowspan=3>D</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan=2>E</td>
    <td rowspan=4>F</td>
  </tr>
  <tr></tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan=2 colspan=2>G</td>
  </tr>
  <tr></tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan=3 colspan=3>H</td>
  </tr>
  <tr></tr>
  <tr></tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan=3>I</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

what I understood with your question is: You want to split the merged cell with same value and then iterate the table simply by row.

I've created a JSFiddle that will split the merged cells with the same value. Then you'll have  a table that can be iterated simply by rows to get the desired output that you specified.

See it running here http://jsfiddle.net/9PZQj/3/

Here's the complete code:

```
<table id="tbl" border = "1">
    <tr>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>B</td>
        <td rowspan="2">C</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>D</td>
        <td rowspan="2">E</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>F</td>
        <td>G</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<br>
<div id="test"> </div>
```

Here's the jquery that is used to manipulate the table's data.

```
   var tempTable = $('#tbl').clone(true);
    var tableBody = $(tempTable).children();
    $(tableBody).children().each(function(index , item){
        var currentRow = item;
        $(currentRow).children().each(function(index1, item1){
            if($(item1).attr("rowspan"))
            {
                // copy the cell
                var item2 = $(item1).clone(true);
                // Remove rowspan
                $(item1).removeAttr("rowspan");
                $(item2).removeAttr("rowspan");
                // last item's index in next row
                var indexOfLastElement = $(currentRow).next().last().index();
                if(indexOfLastElement <= index1)
                {
                     $(currentRow).next().append(item2)
                }
                else
                {
                  // intermediate cell insertion at right position
                  $(item2).insertBefore($(currentRow).next().children().eq(index1))
                }
            }
        });

        console.log(currentRow)
    });

   $('#test').append(tempTable);
```

Comment: This could work, but I do *not* want to change the presentation of the table -- I just want to work in "logical rows", which should of course include a value for each column of the table, as presented.

Comment: Your original table is not changing. Here in this solution I'm creating a copy of the table and adjusting it so that you can have the new udpated table to work upon with same elements but rowspan merged.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/JDMCreator/840c2ad3de2506522a8748a36979ecf8). It supports all the requirements by W3C, even "rowspan=0" (which seems to be only supported by Firefox).

Comment: Please post the relevant, minimal code in your answer - this is far less useful to future searchers in the event that the gist is deleted.